# XML Schema - Element with string, attribute and a sequence?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an element in my XML data that has an attribute AND string, as well as a child sequence. Is there anyway to correctly write a .XSD schema to validate this?

```
<ygg:Attr name="JournalTitleFull">Nature</ygg:Attr>
<ygg:Attr name="JournalIssue">7534</ygg:Attr>
<ygg:Attr name="DOI">10.1038/nature14094</ygg:Attr>
<ygg:Attr name="Year">2015</ygg:Attr>
<ygg:Attr name="JournalTitle">Nature</ygg:Attr>
<ygg:Attr name="Month">Jan</ygg:Attr>
<ygg:Attr name="Day">15</ygg:Attr>
<ygg:Attr name="JournalVolume">517</ygg:Attr>
<ygg:Attr name="Authors">
    <ygg:Value>Neppl, S</ygg:Value><ygg:Value>Ernstorfer, R</ygg:Value>
```

An excerpt from my schema is below but misses the strings of the element (i.e. Nature, 7534, 10.1038/nature14094 etc from above). Any attempt to add the strings to the element renders me unable to add either the attribute and/or child sequence.

```
 <xs:element name="Attr">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="ygg:Value"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:string"/>
```

Note - "ygg:Attr" is defined as a sequence earlier in the schema

Any help would be much appreciated. Please note this is a re-formulated question from earlier, as my prior question caused confusion. Thanks very much!

Comment: The [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/234215) hazard looms large here.  OP's [actual goal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28047084/xml-scheme-pulling-strings-from-attributes#comment44478511_28047084) is to import XML into Excel.

Comment: Whist agreed this is my actual goal, conventional methods of going about this failed. Automatically generated schema have the problem above and Excel also creates this problem when importing without a schema, presumably for the same reason. Therefore, solving the problem (assuming it is possible) above will, by definition, allow excel importation.

Comment: It's not clear what constraints you want to apply on your data (or why). What do you mean by "adding the strings to the element"? You should note that in XSD 1.0, you cannot apply different constraints to sibling elements with the same name. If you want the value to be four digits when @name='Year', you will need XSD 1.1 (conditional type assignment).